# OpenCV ROI and Edge Detection

Tags: android, image, opencv

In Android. In My Surface view (refer to the image I've given the link to) a picture will be taken from the live camera view. I Want to get the RGBA value of these 3 lines by getting the Region of interest and then cropping the image and then getting the RGBA matrix. So First i want to get the Region of Interest for these 3 rectangles and then the RGBA matrix. I cannot get the Region of interest in the surface view. I Need a very simple code.

I am new to OPENCV, So I'm using `JavaCameraView` and `javacameraviewobject.setVisibility(SurfaceView.SUCCESS);` to show the live camera view.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljcNL.jpg]

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Where is the sample image ?

Comment: i edited it please check

Answer (score 1):

Use image enhancement techniques to enhance the ROI and then use thresholding techniques to extract these lines and ROI. Further, you can convert your image into RGBA matrix and get values.

Comment: I am actually trying to get the code. i tried so many examples but still its like not working

Comment: You can't get exact code. You have to write code yourselves. Here, you can only get help if you stuck somewhere in your code.

Comment: I Cannot get that how do i achieve what i want. i just want the 3 lines(or take it as rectangles)cropped in 3 different images so i can get the RGBA matrix for 3 of them. But i am confused b/w the Region of interest method and get contours and edge detection for the 3 rectangles.